# How to setup X-SID , X-AUTH & X-DKIM at windows server 2008 r2 with IIS 7.5

Tags: email, smtp, iis-7.5, dkim, xauth

I am very sad that my legit emails drops to spam box while i receive many spam emails into my inbox. I very rarely send announcement emails to my all registered members (over 400k right now) but most of them dropping the spam box. I am right now comparing one spam email and 1 email sent from my server. It is incredible that spam sender passes everything while i fail.

The below from spam sender

```
    x-store-info:sbevkl2QZR7OXo7WID5ZcVBK1Phj2jX/
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; sender-id=pass (sender IP is 173.193.209.75) header.from=rCv4v5K74iZc2fo0N0n6@konuk.net; dkim=neutral header.d=konuk.net; x-hmca=pass
X-Message-Status: s1:0:n
X-SID-PRA: Kolay Kacamaklar@knknt <rCv4v5K74iZc2fo0N0n6@konuk.net>
X-SID-Result: Pass
X-AUTH-Result: PASS
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MTtHRD0xO1NDTD0x
X-Message-Info: NhFq/7gR1vTmqm72qFhO+pUA1OKFziMdv5bjOox02XYkBtXmlKIMY4JmO5qxJiwlhREOTGOHuM9QG6kRbemms8RStLmbY7U8eh4d25fnpXQ1vXiD8VHGVTpNQGgJsBcE
Received: from s9-75.konuk.net ([173.193.209.75]) by COL0-MC2-F1.Col0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4900);
     Wed, 29 Feb 2012 14:05:06 -0800
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed; s=knet; d=konuk.net;
 h=list-unsubscribe:Content-Type:Date:Message-ID:From:To:in-reply-to:Subject:References;
 bh=qmNH4nW0XriZDjlps/ZVAlabsquKlD83C4hADHvGHLY=;
 b=RkaFe6DVQM6TWfWqSxsrhxq3xHbJebrrvp7XHgPLrz+9icvAcMidKxvBtsr7ei2JE7SIgFCDnuVO
   Up0PKF9vEh8pr5njvgAoN7tO20daHQwJ7p5F4k2vPk6Ajbg+TYlooFYTt3xZyqDFdMnSWNG2wdq3
   hyEUjxzKYNjZrZxQN2g=
DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; c=nofws; q=dns; s=knet; d=konuk.net;
 b=QW8XwevmGtE3MwC/CE1IOzmsfVpmXPsn8uKMwQ1D/1TiTlCGIKGnJjoiI1xoEeMPSnhdTQoPKjDx
   1BxRS0xWmRBuOkknVtcDx85P5yIc2y/8zXqDYcNqhuziWcXAYm3kspr2wG2BdiLY1ZabckF6gIBp
   ikrm9yNBZMIi1NdNpk0=;
Received: by 10.2.17.19 with SMTP id mAgk5xKyY2s4afl86 Mon, 30 Jan 2012 00:04:42 +0200
Received: (qmail 7844 invoked from network); Mon, 30 Jan 2012 00:04:42 +0200
list-unsubscribe: <http://www.konuk.net/system/unsubscribe.php?adress=mypersonalemail@hotmail.com&aid=ixxJ2hBVxasAu5baqU2g3it1qJszuj3xHDlR8mxaeOfo1jwj0npL9vFC1d&lang=Tr&m=118>,<mailto:unsubscribe@konuk.net?subject=unsubscribe-mypersonalemail@hotmail.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="----=_NextOra_000_00eM_08qlk3FT6h.91zFd04984"
Date: Mon, 30 Jan 2012 00:04:42 +0200
Message-ID: <koyvUx=TUNN8h8$-Fv1YEB0u9v$koyvUx=TUNN8h8$@s18.konuk.net>
thread-topic: LOKN - Msnniz varmi
X-Mailer-SenderId: i3JmPJO2N
X-KonukNet-Contentd-ID: {"id":Kjlvi16Jx7B1G}
From: "Kolay Kacamaklar"  @knknt<rCv4v5K74iZc2fo0N0n6@konuk.net> 
To:"mypersonalemail@hotmail.com" 
in-reply-to: 
importance: normal
Subject: LOKN - Msnniz varmi 
References:
Return-Path: rCv4v5K74iZc2fo0N0n6@konuk.net
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 29 Feb 2012 22:05:06.0288 (UTC) FILETIME=[31CB8700:01CCF72E]
```

And now this the email coming from my game (www.monstermmorpg.com) server

```
x-store-info:sbevkl2QZR7OXo7WID5ZcaZ0jeT0hTF6w5JqyzrMGIKOdi/To3RTxhw5VMpmOD49/wJb8aSFHAz8gtkvnM1wWwCvw++5588gflsSDfciyE7JNxhPFkrAVV0MtYSxsRyU
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; sender-id=temperror (sender IP is 85.17.154.139) header.from=noreply@monstermmorpg.com; dkim=none header.d=monstermmorpg.com; x-hmca=none
X-Message-Status: n:0:n
X-SID-PRA: MonsterMMORPG <noreply@monstermmorpg.com>
X-DKIM-Result: None
X-AUTH-Result: NONE
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0xO0Q9MTtHRD0xO1NDTD0w
X-Message-Info: NhFq/7gR1vR2/tk3mTx4qpcYBpD4z9TE0YneWG8TVeLz542JbpQDH0fPkI7chBK4X+cC9sILd0Cv76nvVUP73k9QX3qsgI9HS9rs2TeqE7lEZfvsXhUGXDfgtly1++/OW95jTqDpfU4=
Received: from noreply.monstermmorpg.com ([85.17.154.139]) by SNT0-MC1-F38.Snt0.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.4900);
     Sat, 10 Mar 2012 07:51:48 -0800
Received: from XCPV002 ([85.17.154.139]) by noreply.monstermmorpg.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.17514);
     Sat, 10 Mar 2012 15:51:48 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: "MonsterMMORPG"
 <noreply@monstermmorpg.com>
To: mypersonalemail@hotmail.com
Date: 10 Mar 2012 15:51:48 +0000
Subject: =?utf-8?B?UG9rZW1vbkNyYWZ0IGRhaGEga2FsaXRlbGkgYmlyIG95dW4g?=
 =?utf-8?B?b2xhcmFrIGdlcmkgZMO2bmTDvC4gRXNraSBoZXNhYsSxbsSxeiBkdXJ1?=
 =?utf-8?B?eW9yLg==?=
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Return-Path: noreply@monstermmorpg.com
Message-ID: <XCPV002jCRGryWtIIZS0004e7c3@noreply.monstermmorpg.com>
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 10 Mar 2012 15:51:48.0950 (UTC) FILETIME=[B4127760:01CCFED5]
```

I am seriously desperate about this. How do i set up ?

I am using C# 4.0 WPF application. Using windows server 2008 R2 and IIS 7.5

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### DNS

Configure your server to use a fully qualified DNS name that reserves through a reverse lookup. My own personal mail server would reject your email during the initial exchange, never receiving the content and causing a failed delivery. You server is currently introducing itself to the internet at "XCPV002".

Change your SMTP server's configuration to use its full hostname and make sure that your DNS server has matching `A` and `PTR` records.

### Content

UTF-8 subject line... probably a bad idea. Looks like gibberish and gibberish looks like spam.

Fix your headers. Both the From: and Sender: headers are showing up on two lines. Figure out why it shows up and remove the IP address in the Sender: field.

All the issues from this category relate to the software which is generating your email before your SMTP server sees it.

### Follow up

DNS entry looks good.

```
$ host 85.17.154.139
139.154.17.85.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer noreply.monstermmorpg.com.
$ host noreply.monstermmorpg.com
noreply.monstermmorpg.com has address 85.17.154.139
```

Regarding UTF-8: that may vary. If you need it to represent certain characters, then by all means do make use of it. My instinct is that spam filters often weight gibberish characters or misspellings negatively. If your filtering software isn't UTF-8 aware, it will just see the ASCII line above.

Where you site may have non-English users, UTF-8 is required for representing many languages, and most of the Internet has "gotten there," it may be me that needs to revisit that view. From that perspective, test the other changes out and see if they're enough. It may be that UTF-8 is just fine these days.

Comment: Thanks but i need more detailed information. If i were experienced like you i would not waste my time to ask here. I also setup reverse lookup but i don't know why that fails with hotmail.

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG I pointed to which parts of the system are responsible for the different issues, but I'm not sure that I can go much further than that without getting my hands dirty.

Comment: hello. made some improvements as you said. can you check my a record and ptr record are correct ? also i don't get why utf8 subject is bad ? thank you.